# How to get date object for desired date in java?

Tags: java, date

I have a date object like,

```
Date d = new Date();
```

which will return current date and time. But I need to assign this date object for my desired date. Eg: after one week from current date like that without using Calendar class in java. Is there anyway? There is a constructor like,

```
Date d = new Date(millis);
```

which will give the date from Jan 1, 1970 to the millis added value. So is there any way to know this millis for one week after from the current date. One week is just for example, it can be one week or one month or two months.

Comment: May I interest you in the `java.time` package, introduced in Java 8?

Comment: Don't use Date and Calendar. They're old, obsolete, clumsy. Use the classes from the java.time package, which are much cleaner. To know how to use them, you do as for any other class: you read their documentation.

Comment: Can you give an exact point about what you want to do ?

Comment: Why can't you use `Calendar`?  Is this a homework assignment or some sort of personal challenge?  Or did your employer/client tell you not to use `Calendar` because it's obsolete and they want you to use a current part of the API?

Comment: Let's say today Dec 13. But i need to have my date object value as Dec 18. How to do that?

Comment: Zach Pedigo would like to comment: First off, yes there is a way but I'm also not completely sure what you are asking or what you are trying to do, can you add some more code for clarity? What do you mean "Eg: after one week from current date like that without using `Calendar` class in java"?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
java.util.Date                   // The terrible awful nasty old class that you should never use. Represents a moment in UTC, with a resolution of milliseconds.
.from(                           // Convert from modern class to legacy class.
    Instant                      // Represent a moment in UTC, with a resolution of nanoseconds.
    .now()                       // Capture the current moment in UTC.
    .plus(                       // Add some span-of-time.
        Duration.ofDays( 7 )     // Generic chunks of 24-hours, without regard for the calendar.
    )                            // Returns another `Instant` object, per immutable objects pattern.
)                                // Returns a legacy `java.util.Date` object.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

Never use `java.util.Date`. That is a terrible class, with many flaws. Supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). You can convert back-and-forth using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

> after one week from current date

Define a “week”. Do you mean adding seven calendar dates? If so, what time-of-day do want on the resulting date? If not, do you mean adding a series of seven generic 24-hour days?

## 7 * 24 hours

If you mean to add seven generic 24-hour days, use `Instant` with a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) A `Duration` is a count of whole seconds plus a fractional second in nanos.

Perhaps this is what you meant by that mysterious mention in your Question of “without `Calendar class”. That class would apply a time zone, while a`java.util.Date` is in UTC.

```
Duration sevenChunksOf24Hours = Duration.ofDays( 7 ) ;  // *NOT* calendar days.
Instant now = Instant.now() ;                           // Capture current moment in UTC.
Instant later = now.plus( d ) ;                         // Add the duration to the `Instant` thereby generating another `Instant`.
```

## Seven calendar days

Adding days means working with dates on the calendar. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Add seven *calendar* days.

```
LocalDate weekLater = today.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

To get a moment we need to specify a time-of-day and a time zone. If you want the first moment of the day, let *java.time* determine that moment. Never assume 00:00 as the start of the day. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) can mean the day starts at another time such as 01:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = weekLater.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

If you want to see that same value through the wall-clock time of UTC, extract an `Instant`. An `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> One week is just for example, it can be one week or one month or two months.

In this case, rather than hard-coding a call to `LocalDate::plusWeeks`, pass in a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) (a count of years-weeks-months-days) and call [`LocalDate::plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plus(java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount)). A `Period` uses calendar-days, *not* generic 24-hour days. Days in the calendar may turn out to be any length, such a 23, 23.5, 25 hours, all irrelevant with a `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths( 2 ) ;
LocalDate later = today.plus( p ) ;                // Pass a `Period` for an number of years-weeks-months-days. A `Period` uses calendar-days, *not* generic 24-hour periods of time.
ZonedDateTime zdt = weekLater.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

If you need a `java.util.Date` to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to your question

> But I need to assign this date object for my desired date
>   So is there any way to know this millis for one week after from the
>   current date. One week is just for example, it can be one week or one
>   month or two months.

I assume that you want to give a date and check it is after or before some other. You can achieve it using java 8 timing package as below:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2018,12,13,20,0,0,0);

System.out.println(ldt.plusDays(5).isAfter(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

output is: `true` .

You can compare `LocalDateTime.now()` it self with another localDateTime or you can set the exact date and using `plusDays() plusMonths()` methods to add day/month/hours etc.

Or you can compare your `Date` now with some days after it using LocalDateTime as below :

```
Date date = new Date();

LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

System.out.println(ld.isAfter(ld.plusDays(5)));
```

output is : `false`

Comment: This Answer was headed on the right track, but got derailed by using `LocalDateTime`. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such a `LocalDateTime` *cannot* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. So it should not be used in code tracking a moment, the current moment in this case.